# Computer only detects SSD after booting twice

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd, bios

This is a problem I have been having for years on an old laptop that I don't use anymore, but it wasn't a big deal to me so I never bothered to fix it. I just recently put Windows 10 on it for my parents to use, and I'd rather fix the problem before I give it to them. When I used the laptop I had it on Linux Mint and I had the same problem, so it isn't OS related.

I removed the hard drive of my laptop (HP Probook 4330s) to put in a 64GB SSD (OCZ Vertex 4).

Since then, **when I boot the laptop, it tells me "BootDevice not found", I press Escape, it restarts, tells me to press Escape to continue booting, and then boots normally** (here's a gif to make it clear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGlFH.jpg). 
It's like the drive takes too long to start and isn't detected the first time it boots (which I find weird for an SSD).

I've tried to change most options in the BIOS settings, but I never see any change (here are the BIOS settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJbTa.jpg).
I also just flashed the BIOS to the latest version I could find on HP's website, but I don't see any difference.

And something else that I just noticed on Windows 10, if I try to put the computer to sleep, it won't be able to restart. It will just say "your computer encountered a problem" and restarts a few times doing checks on the drive. I assume it's linked to the first problem, something about the disk.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: As it is an old computer, it is possible that the "CMOS battery" is dead. If you search for "hp probook 4330s cmos battery location" you'll find videos on how to get to it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's not the CMOS battery, I've tried a few things to test it and it seems to work properly. Also, you say it's an old computer, but I had this problem even when the computer was new, as I said it appeared when I switched the original hard drive for an SSD. I'll try to see if I still have the original hard drive and try booting with it.

Comment: You might as well switch off the "CD-ROM boot" through "USB device boot" in the BIOS.

Comment: I tried that. It, unfortunately, doesn't help.